# Is there an api that extract table data from pictures?

Tags: json, excel, api

I'm developing an app that deals with documents and images that contain tables in them and covert them to excel format. I want to integrate the "Insert data from picture" feature in it like [this] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7#ID0EAABAAA=iOS/Android)
Is there an api that I can use to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome @Yas to Stackoverflow. Your question requires additional details for you to receive any help. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Google `OCR API` keyword and you'll find too many online services like [Google Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr), [OCRApiService](http://ocrapiservice.com/), [NanoNets](https://nanonets.com/ocr-api/?&utm_source=nanonets.com%2Fblog%2F&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=Extract%20Text%20from%20Image%20&%20PDF%20%7C%20Free%20Online%20OCR%20API) that provide OCR API

Your first challenge is when the document contains information other than a table, like photos, paragraphs, lists and etc, so, you should use image processing in order to detect and extract tables from the document, and pass the table to these services in order to extract text and save into excel.

Most of the services only extract the raw text and cannot draw a table for them. This could be your second challenge.